# Strange result of MatrixFunction

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, special-functions

Let us consider the sum of the matrix series

```
m = 2; n = 3; Sum[MatrixPower[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, m + k*n]/(m + n*k)!, {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

> {{-(32 E^(-(5/4) - Sqrt[33]/
>          2) (-11 E^(15/4) - Sqrt[33] E^(15/4) - 11 E^(15/4 + Sqrt[33]) +
>            Sqrt[33] E^(15/4 + Sqrt[33]) + 
>           22 E^((3 Sqrt[33])/4)
>             Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] - 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])] + 
>           2 Sqrt[33] E^((3 Sqrt[33])/4)
>             Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] - 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])] + 
>           22 E^(Sqrt[33]/4)
>             Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] + 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])] - 
>           2 Sqrt[33] E^(Sqrt[33]/4)
>             Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] + 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])]))/(33 (-5 + 
>           Sqrt[33])^2 (5 + Sqrt[33])^2), (128 E^(-(5/4) - Sqrt[33]/
>         2) (-E^(15/4) + E^(15/4 + Sqrt[33]) + 
>          2 E^((3 Sqrt[33])/4)
>            Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] - 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])] - 
>          2 E^(Sqrt[33]/4)
>            Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] + 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])]))/(3 Sqrt[
>        33] (-5 + Sqrt[33])^2 (5 + Sqrt[33])^2)}, {(64 E^(-(5/4) - Sqrt[
>         33]/2) (-E^(15/4) + E^(15/4 + Sqrt[33]) + 
>          2 E^((3 Sqrt[33])/4)
>            Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] - 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])] - 
>          2 E^(Sqrt[33]/4)
>            Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] + 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])]))/(Sqrt[
>        33] (-5 + Sqrt[33])^2 (5 + Sqrt[33])^2), (32 E^(-(5/4) - Sqrt[
>         33]/2) (11 E^(15/4) - Sqrt[33] E^(15/4) + 
>          11 E^(15/4 + Sqrt[33]) + Sqrt[33] E^(15/4 + Sqrt[33]) - 
>          22 E^((3 Sqrt[33])/4)
>            Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] - 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])] + 
>          2 Sqrt[33] E^((3 Sqrt[33])/4)
>            Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] - 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])] - 
>          22 E^(Sqrt[33]/4)
>            Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] + 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])] - 
>          2 Sqrt[33] E^(Sqrt[33]/4)
>            Sin[1/12 (15 Sqrt[3] + 9 Sqrt[11] + 2 [Pi])]))/(33 (-5 + 
>          Sqrt[33])^2 (5 + Sqrt[33])^2)}}

```
 N[%]
```

> {{17.2105,24.9822},{37.4733,54.6839}}

It should be noticed the above results are the same since version 7.
On the other hand, the matrix series under consideration can be expressed in terms of  an entire function `MittagLefflerE` from the matrix `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function) and [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MittagLefflerE.html) to this end). Thus,

```
MatrixFunction[#^m*MittagLefflerE[m, n, #^n] &, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
```

> {{-(((-3 - Sqrt[33]) (5 - Sqrt[33])^2 MittagLefflerE[2, 3, 
>         1/8 (5 - Sqrt[33])^3])/(
>       8 Sqrt[33])) + ((-3 + Sqrt[33]) (5 + Sqrt[33])^2 MittagLefflerE[2,
>         3, 1/8 (5 + Sqrt[33])^3])/(
>      8 Sqrt[33]), -(((-3 - Sqrt[33]) (3 - Sqrt[33]) (5 - Sqrt[
>          33])^2 MittagLefflerE[2, 3, 1/8 (5 - Sqrt[33])^3])/(
>       48 Sqrt[33])) - ((-3 - Sqrt[33]) (-3 + Sqrt[33]) (5 + Sqrt[
>         33])^2 MittagLefflerE[2, 3, 1/8 (5 + Sqrt[33])^3])/(
>      48 Sqrt[33])}, {-(1/4) Sqrt[3/
>       11] (5 - Sqrt[33])^2 MittagLefflerE[2, 3, 1/8 (5 - Sqrt[33])^3] + 
>      1/4 Sqrt[3/
>       11] (5 + Sqrt[33])^2 MittagLefflerE[2, 3, 
>        1/8 (5 + Sqrt[33])^3], -(((3 - Sqrt[33]) (5 - Sqrt[
>          33])^2 MittagLefflerE[2, 3, 1/8 (5 - Sqrt[33])^3])/(
>       8 Sqrt[33])) - ((-3 - Sqrt[33]) (5 + Sqrt[33])^2 MittagLefflerE[2,
>         3, 1/8 (5 + Sqrt[33])^3])/(8 Sqrt[33])}}

```
N[%]
```

> {{5686.18, 8287.09}, {12430.6, 18116.8}}

The results should be the same, is not so? Hope one feels the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `(m + n k)!` when you should have used `(m + n k - 1)!`. Also, you have the argument order backwards in the [`MittagLefflerE`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MittagLefflerE) function. Correcting those errors:

```
m = 2;
n = 3;
mat = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Sum[MatrixPower[mat, m + k n]/(m + n k - 1)!, {k, 0, Infinity}] //N
```

> {{92.1812, 134.146}, {201.219, 293.4}}

Compared to:

```
MatrixFunction[#^m MittagLefflerE[n, m, #^n]&, mat] //N
```

> {{92.1812, 134.146}, {201.219, 293.4}}

Comment: Thank you. However, you changed the series. I should use MittagLefflerE(m+1,n,#^n) in the second case. In this case the results coincide. I am glad MMA is right.